# How can I use RestTemplate to verify a Wiremock Fault in integration test?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, wiremock

I have written a number of successful tests to prove the HttpStatus code is being returned correctly, however I am  now looking to verify the Fault code returned as below. Usually I would say

```
 assertThat(actualResponse.getStatusCode(), is(status));
```

to get the Http status code. How can I verify the Fault code? I currently have the below, but I am unsure how to return the fault code from the actualResponse body.

```
public void shouldReturnSuitableStatusCodeForScenario(String requestFileName,Fault fault, String actualResponseFileName) throws JSONException {
    //Given
    String createRequest = readJsonFromFile(DIRECTORY, requestFileName);

    //When
    ResponseEntity<String> actualResponse = stub.postForEntity(HTTP_LOCALHOST_8081 + "/v1/transaction/", createRequest, String.class);

    //Then
    assertThat(actualResponse, is(fault));
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(readJsonFromFile(DIRECTORY, actualResponseFileName), actualResponse.getBody(), true);
}
```

Current stub, omitted some code for brevit:

```
.willReturn(aResponse() .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) .withFault(Fault.MALFORMED_RESPONSE_CHUNK) .withBodyFile("/malformed_chunk_response.json")));
```

Comment: Like `actualResponse.getStatusCode()`?

Comment: but for the fault code rather than the status code. They are 2 different things

Answer (score 1):

In the case you're expecting an error (I'm assuming that `stub` is a `RestTemplate`), one way to can extract both the status code and the error body is like this:

```java
String statusText;
int statusCode;

stub.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return response.statusCode.isError()
    }

    @Override
    void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        statusText = response.getStatusText();
        statusCode = response.rawStatusCode;
    }
});

stub.postForEntity(HTTP_LOCALHOST_8081 + "/v1/transaction/", createRequest, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my original question to show my current stub. Is it possible to say get status 500 code then go down a layer to retrieve the malformed chunk response?

Comment: Ah, you want to retrieve the status code that is being returned? Or do you want both the status code and the body?

Comment: Updated my answer to what I think you're asking

Comment: I want the fault code, which is different to the Http status code

Comment: Fault type, like something such as MALFORMED_RESPONSE

Comment: It is not possible to directly do what you would like. `Fault` is an implementation detail of Wiremock, and Spring has no idea what that is. As per the [Wiremock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults) `MALFORMED_RESPONSE_CHUNK` will just send garbage as the body. I don't see the usefulness of writing a test to see "is this garbage?" Since this is an integration test, probably you want to test your app's behavior when it receives garbage, rather than analyzing the garbage itself.